# Bootstrap 4 carousel not working because of jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I'm taking a Bootstrap 4 course and the task I'm required to do uses jQuery to create pause and play buttons in a carousel. While doing it in my computer, I use node modules to import jQuery, popper.js and Bootstrap JavaScript, but I also want to host the project in GitHub, so I added some imports with Internet links. The problem is that the jQuery functions I'm using are incompatible with the jQuery remotely hosted. The JavaScript code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mycarousel").carousel({
        interval: 2000
    });

    $("#carousel-pause").click(function () {
        $("#mycarousel").carousel("pause");
    });
    $("#carousel-play").click(function () {
        $("#mycarousel").carousel("cycle");
    });
});
```

The jQuery remotely hosted is version 3.5.1

Comment: What's the error you get? That code looks quite standard to me.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I don't get an error, the button simply doesn't work